# Structure within structure

Tags: c, memory

Can anybody please help me with the following code? The program runs correctly.

These are my questions:

1. Why is the dot operator working in c?
2. Why am I able to access stack structure (i.e `s1`) twice when I allocated only enough memory for one struct?  How did it become an array?
3. Can anybody please explain how is memory getting allocated here?

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{    
    struct mynode
    {
        int val;
        struct mynode *next;    
    } node;        
} stack;

int main()
{
    stack *s1;
    s1=(stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack));


    s1[0].node.val=10;
    s1[1].node.val=20;
    printf("%d",s1[1].node.val);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I honestly don't know how you are accessing s1[1].  Technically the stack only has 1 element and that is a struct.  When you do sizeof it allocates what is in the struct stack which is assume 4 bytes for the int and x-bytes for the node pointer.

Comment: @Alex: Segmentation. So long as his random pointer dereferences (by chance) fall within his memory segment, C won't complain, and he'll receive whatever garbage happens to sit at that memory location. As soon as he reaches outside of his segment, the kernel will likely kill his process.

Answer (score 10):

1. I've no idea what you mean. The dot operator accesses a struct's member, that's what it does.
2. You can't, you're doing something illegal. C has no mechanisms to stop you doing bad things, though your program will crash if you do something bad "enough". You get lucky here.
   It didn't become an array, you're just treating it like one. The compiler can't tell if it's a pointer to one element or multiple (an array) so it lets you treat any pointer like an array. It's up to you to make sure that's a valid thing to do.
3. malloc.

Comment: Expanding on point 2, you've allocated space for one object (or, equivalently, for an array with a length of 1). Attempting to access the *second* element of that array is an error, but not one that the implementation is required to catch. You're probably clobbering unallocated memory. Expanding on point 3, `malloc()` is defined by the language to allocate a memory block of a specified size (or to return a null pointer if it fails to do so). The language says nothing about *how* it does this, and 99% of the time you don't need to care.

Comment: Also on point 2), Its not about an array. You need to understand how `[]` works. The compiler expands `s1[1]` as `*(s1+1)` which translates to increment the address of `s1` by `1*sizeof(stack)` and point to the data residing at that address. Since it is within the heap segment, C has no issues. You can put whatever value you want there. But try doing a `free(&s1[1])` and you see that you get a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

1) The dot operator in C is just a language construct that allows you to access members of a structure. You are using it  to access the member of a structure,SO it's perfectly legal.There is no reason why it shouldn't work.

In C# you can also use "." to call a function inside an object.
That is to say,if you have the following class in C#

```
public class foo()
{
  public void print_hello()
  {
    Console.Writeline("Hello,World");
  }  

 }
```

You would use it in the following way:

```
foo object1 = new foo();
foo.print_hello();
```

2)

The line

```
  stack *s1
```

declares s1 as a pointer to the structure stat.But this isn't the end of it.You can use this to point to several regions of memory,each one containing a stack structure.

When you declare an array (for example an array of int) you can do it the traditional way.

```
int  integersArray [10];
```

(this way the program allocates memory automatically,without you having to worry about it).
You can also use pointers.In wich case you would declare your array as follows.

```
  int * integersArray;
```

This can be a pointer to one or various segments of memory,depending on how you allocate it.
Please note that the above code unlike the previous one,does not allocate memory,it simply declares a pointer to a structure.You need to explicitly allocate memory by doing

```
  integersArray = malloc(10*sizeOf(int));
```

Wich will allocate enough memory to hold 10 times the size of an int.That is,10 integers.
In both cases you can use integersArray as a normal array and the code

```
printf("%d",integersArray[0]);
```

works.
In the second case you can move trough the array by incrementing or decrementing the pointer.
By doing

```
integersArray++
```

You are moving the pointer to the next memory section.If you do integersArray+=11; ,given that your array has 10 positions,you are now in an invalid segment of memory and anything can happen (if you end up in a protected memory segment,your program,as pointed out in a comment above WILL be terminated).

@Alex: Segmentation. So long as his random pointer dereferences (by chance) fall within his memory segment, C won't complain, and he'll receive whatever garbage happens to sit at that memory location. As soon as he reaches outside of his segment, the kernel will likely kill his process. – jforberg 1 hour ago

Your program is basically doing the same thing,but using s1 instead.

3) This part of your code

```
s1=(stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack));
```

is allocating memory,enough as to hold one structure of type stack.
In generall,to allocate memory for n elements you would do

```
yourPointer = malloc(n*sizeof(structure));
```

So why is your program working when you try to access your structure like this?

```
     s1[1].node.val=20;
    printf("%d",s1[1].node.val);
```

My best guess is that you are lucky enough to be accessing valid memory.But this may not allways be the case. I suggest you to be very carefull when dealing with dynamic memory.

NOTE: even if the above was clear enough I strongly recomend you to check K&R's book,wich explains it more clearly.

Comment: So when do we use "." and when do we use "->" to access structure elements?

Comment: @PravinKesari `a->b` is syntactic sugar for `(*a).b`, so you only use it when `a` has pointer-to-struct type.  The array index operator is also syntactic sugar: `a[i].b` is equivalent to `(*(a+i)).b`.  Does that help?

Comment: (Yes, if we were designing C from scratch today, it might be better to allow `.` to auto-dereference a pointer on its left.  But that's not the world we live in.)

Comment: @Zack Thanks Zack.Now I get it.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you has only one struct alocated :

`s1=(stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack));`

For two alocations try :

`s1=(stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack) * 2);`

Comment: The OP asked three questions. You didn't answer any of them.

Answer (score 0):

This code is more in depth than what you are writing.  I'll get you started on setting this up, but I suggest you look up the topic 'Linked Lists' in C because this does not act like a stack at all.

Here is some code for the structs to get you started with the implementation.  This works for your case, but you might want to create an initializer and an addNode function if you want to keep going.  Heres a link so you can learn more about linked lists:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24684/How-to-create-Linked-list-using-C-C

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
typedef struct _node_ {
    int val;
    struct _node_ * next;
}mynode;

typedef struct _linkedlist_ {
    mynode * node;
}linkedlist;


int main() {
linkedlist * s1 = (linkedlist*) malloc(sizeof(linkedlist));
s1->node = malloc(sizeof(mynode));
s1->node->next = malloc(sizeof(mynode));
s1->node->val = 10;
s1->node->next->val = 20;
printf("%d",s1->node->next->val);
free(s1->node->next);
free(s1->node);
free(s1);
//getch(); //don't know what this is for
return 0;
```

}

Comment: How about attending the questions the OP asked? And the getch() may be to keep a console window from closing before the user sees the output.